# Issue with loading pages with AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, routes

Stumped. No issue with my code (as far as I can see), and it loads `list-patents.htm` template when nothing is selected, but fails to load `add-patents` template when the corresponding anchor tag is clicked. URL displays as follows:

`http://localhost/#!/#list-patents`

Any reason why the content isn't loading? Is it possibly the `#!` in the URL?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>

<main ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#list-patents">List patents</li>
                <li><a href="#add-patent">Add patent</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section class="ng-view">

        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    $scope.stages = [
        {'stage': 'green', 'cost': '$1, 500'},
        {'stage': 'yellow', 'cost': '$1, 800'},
        {'stage': 'red', 'cost': '$2, 100'},
        {'stage': 'blue', 'cost': '$2, 500'},
        {'stage': 'brown', 'cost': '$2, 900'}
    ];
    $http.get('../scripts/patent-renewal.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.application = response.data.patents;
    });

});

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/list-patents.htm',
        controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
    .when('/add-patent', {
        templateUrl:'../templates/add-patent.htm',
        controller: 'appCtrl'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!#` might indeed be the problem, why it's added no idea.

What you could try is to switch to html5 mode

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And then your href can be direct, without `#`:

```
<li><a href="list-patents">List patents</li>
<li><a href="add-patent">Add patent</li>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, had to specify a base URL and as you stated remove the `#`. Still would like to know why there is an issue..... anyways, thanks again